# VBA Extract series collection values

Tags: excel, plot, graph, numbers, vba

I have a chart and want to draw an arrow between two points. The two points are from two different series, but have the same x value.

In order to do this, I feel I have to know the y value of the plot points, and the y axis minimum and maximum scale. From this, I should be able to plot an arrow.

My question is how do I get the y values? I don't want to get them off the table as I'm iterating through many charts.

I would have thought I'd do something like:

```
Sub Tester()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim PA_w, PA_h, PA_l, PA_t, min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y, _
x_node1, x_node2, y_node1, y_node2 As Double
Dim Npts, i As Integer
Dim s As Shape

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
        cht.Activate
        For Each s In cht.Chart.Shapes
            If Not (s.Type = msoAutoShape) Then s.Delete
        Next s
        Set s1 = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(3)
        Set s2 = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(4)
        Npts = s1.Points.Count
        PA_w = cht.Chart.PlotArea.InsideWidth
        PA_h = cht.Chart.PlotArea.InsideHeight
        PA_l = cht.Chart.PlotArea.InsideLeft
        PA_t = cht.Chart.PlotArea.InsideTop
        max_x = cht.Chart.Axes(1).MaximumScale
        min_x = cht.Chart.Axes(1).MinimumScale
        max_y = cht.Chart.Axes(2).MaximumScale
        min_y = cht.Chart.Axes(2).MinimumScale
        For i = 0 To 4
            With cht.Chart.Shapes.AddLine(PA_l + i * PA_w / 4, PA_t, PA_l + i * PA_w / 4, 4 * PA_t + PA_h).Line
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
    Next i
    With cht.Chart.Shapes
        .AddLine(PA_l, PA_t, PA_l + PA_w, PA_t).Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .AddLine(PA_l, PA_t + PA_h, PA_l + PA_w, PA_t + PA_h).Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
        For i = 1 To Npts
            x_node1 = PA_l + (s1.XValues(i) - min_x) * PA_w / (max_x - min_x)
            x_node2 = PA_l + (s2.XValues(i) - min_x) * PA_w / (max_x - min_x)
            y_node1 = PA_t + (max_y - s1.Values(i)) * PA_h / (max_y - min_y)
            y_node2 = PA_t + (max_y - s2.Values(i)) * PA_h / (max_y - min_y)

            Set myShape = cht.Shapes.AddLine(x_node1, y_node1, x_node2, y_node2)
            With myShape.Line
                .EndArrowheadLength = msoArrowheadLong
                .EndArrowheadWidth = msoArrowheadWidthMedium
                .EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
            End With
        Next i
    Next cht
Next sht

CurrentSheet.Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I would have thought that'd work, but I just get a runtime and automation error :( The error seems to be in the final for-loop and caused by the .Values and .XValues references in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You could use data labels or markers that are formatted to not show and play with the geometry.

```
Sub c()

Dim c As Chart
Dim s As Series
Dim d As DataLabel

Set c = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
Set s = c.SeriesCollection(2)
Set d = s.DataLabels(1)

Debug.Print d.Text, d.Top


End Sub
```

Comment: Tried using datalabels, but it doesn't want to read them and throws up an error

Comment: what did you try, you have to set hasdatalabels to true and I trust you added the datalabels to the series.